# tadvstringgrid not copying every cell

Tags: properties, c++builder, copy-paste, tstringgrid

I have this tadvStringGrid
it has:

```
navigation.allowclipboardAlways=true
navigation.allowclipboardshortcut=true
option.goRangeSelect = true 
MouseActions.DisjunctRowSelect = true
goEditing=true
```

I can select multiple cells but when i ctrl-c and ctrl-v ( at another location) only the last cell selected is copied.
Is there a property which needs to be turned on to have all the cells copied.
Or do i have to create a list of the selected cells and copy them at the new location?

ex:
Table:

1 2 3 4  5  6

7 8 9 10 11 12

if i i select 1,2,7 (ctrl-c them)
then click on cell 4 and ctrl-v
the 4 will change to 7 but the rest will remain unchanged.
i would like for 4 to become 1, 5 to become 2 and 10 to become 7.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

After much searching.
To solve my issue, i had to turn off editing
which gave me acces to all the selected cells.
I saved the X Y coordinate with its value in a temp variable on the copy event
Made a list of those variable and on the paste event i would copy the list to the desired location.

This is more complicated way than needed but i cant find the easy way. so if anyone has a clue, I'll take it

thank you